# Complete the function so that it returns the index at which value can be found in the array, or -1 if value

Tags: javascript, callback

I am trying to understand the below function. why we create a new function  with "item" and "index" as parameters inside the indexOf function? I mean I don't understand how the iteration helper `each` works? what would be different if we use for loop?

The questions: 
Returns the index at which value can be found in the array, or -1 if value is not present in the array. Here's an example of a function that needs to iterate instead of using a standard `for` loop, though,it uses the iteration helper `each`

```
_.indexOf = function(array, target){
    var result = -1;

    _.each(array, function(item, index) {
      if (item === target && result === -1) {
        result = index;
      }
    });

    return result;
  };
```

Comment: Assuming that Underscore.js is used: http://underscorejs.org/#each

Comment: Maybe you should read [forEach documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)